# PDF created with Html2pdf and how to save different name for pdf document

Tags: php, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf sucessfully created pdf, then I want to save pdf with different name based on the textbox value.

```
<?php

$diff_name=$_POST['name'];

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

// save different name
$html2pdf->Output('$diff_name.pdf', 'F');

?>
<html>
 <body>
  <input type="text" name="name" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is so old, but maybe somebody else will need the response.

```
$html2pdf->pdf->setTitle('my nice browser title');
```

This will control the output of the browser title.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML output is incomplete.

Try this:

```
<?php
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));

// build new name and commit
$newname=$_POST['name'].'.pdf';
$html2pdf->Output($newname, 'F');
?>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test page</title>
<head>
<body>
 <form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to save textbox name.pdf

Comment: finally i got a answer


    my answer
       //add 
      $diiffname=($pdf.'.pdf');

      $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
      $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
      $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
      $pdf=$_POST['name']; 
      
      //chenge
      $html2pdf->Output($diffname, 'F');


        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Test page</title>
        <head>
        <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
  </body></html>

Comment: I updated my answer to fix to your solution. Please note that the input is not validated. In this case it is possible to write the outputfile anywhere!

Comment: I too faced issue with file name when I passed japanese text  for filename. I am able to download Japanese text in pdf file, but file name is empty.