# Set Custom Page Title for HTML2PDF created pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I am using HTML2PDF library of PHP to create PDF from HTML. My page url is as below ::

```
http://domain.com/admin/invoice/invoicedownload
```

To create pdf using below code ::

```
ob_start();
$width_in_mm = 240;
$height_in_mm = 250;
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', array($width_in_mm,$height_in_mm), en, true, 'UTF-8', array(15, 10, 15, 10));
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetTitle('Invoice Details');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($pdf_template);
$html2pdf->Output($file_name,'I');
die();
```

This code open pdf view in browser new tab.

Issue I am facing is that that new tab title is set as "Invoice Details - invoicedownload" but I want it as "Invoice Details". Always url's last part is append in title.

Please help me for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to put title in html. possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/9466303/679743

Comment: Already tried but did not worked for me

Answer (score 3):

In order to define your own tab title, you can use the 'embed' html tag.

File n°1 (main):

```css
html, body, embed
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Your title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <embed src=/path-to-your-pdf type='application/pdf'/>
        </body>
    </html>
```

File n°2 (/path-to-your-pdf):

```
<?php
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P, 'A4', 'en');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($pdf_template);
$html2pdf->output();
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/tcpdf_methods.md

```
$html2pdf->pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetTitle("title");
$html2pdf->pdf->SetSubject('subject');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetKeywords('keyword1,keyword2');
```